# LdapEnforceChannelBinding Configuration for Windows

Tags: windows, ldap

We got a request from our client to verify if our software will support Windows LDAP authentication with the security patches in mid Jan 2020.

Microsoft has provided a way to test the compatibility of your software by manually configuring few things.

In essence, organizations are being asked to add LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing configuration changes to make authentications via LDAP on Active Directory Domain Controllers more secure.

Below is the link for the background understanding.

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV190023

I am referring the below link to configure LdapEnforceChannelBinding :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4034879/how-to-add-the-ldapenforcechannelbinding-registry-entry

I am not clear on few of the things like (Please refer the above link):

1. Path for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) domain controllers: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters

> Question: I don't see any parameter folder under NTDS. Do I need to
>   create a dummy one?

Path for Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) servers: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\\Parameters

> Question: What should be the LDS instance name here , can I create
>   with any name?

DWORD: LdapEnforceChannelBinding

> Question: Where should a add this key as DWORD.

I have never done the changes before so asking the question, if my question sounds stupid please forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions (this may be more appropriate on server fault):

Yes you can create the Key called Parameters by right clicking on the NTDS Key and choosing New -> Key then typing Parameters and press enter.

I would ignore AD LDS configuration unless you have configured an AD LDS instance, and if you have configured AD LDS you would know more about what to do here.

If you right click on the newly created Parameters folder and choose New -> DWORD (32 bit) value, then type in LdapEnforceChannelBinding and press enter, this should create the new value. You can then right click on the value and choose modify, entering either 0 (disabled), 1 (best effort) or 2 (enforced) as to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Do we have any reference/doc for this. Let me know.

Comment: how do you validate the applications with this security fix?